Get an editBox value from customui ribbon
I've used the below code on "Thisworkbook" for customize myribbon, however i can't be able to get the values of the editBox.
can anyone please sort out me in favour.
I can't generate callbacks with custom UI editor as this is not allowed/installed to use. so i used as below
Private Sub Workbook_Activate()

Dim hFile As Long

Dim path5 As String, fileName10 As String, ribbonXML As String, user As String

hFile = FreeFile

user = Environ("Username")

path5 = "C:\\Users\\" & user & "\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Office\\"

fileName10 = "Excel.officeUI"

ribbonXML = "\<mso:customUI      xmlns:mso='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui' onLoad = 'onLoad'\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  \<mso:ribbon startFromScratch = 'true'\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    \<mso:qat/\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    \<mso:tabs\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      \<mso:tab id='welcome' label='AMP Cmd Buttons' insertBeforeQ='mso:TabFormat'\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        \<mso:group id='AMPgroup' label='ClearData' autoScale='true'\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          \<mso:button id='Delete1' label='ClearAll' " & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "imageMso='InkEraseMode'      onAction='Clear_data'/\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        \</mso:group\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          \<mso:editBox id='editBox' getText='editBox1' " & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "     label='Location'  onChange='editBox2'/\> " & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        \</mso:group\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "      \</mso:tab\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "    \</mso:tabs\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "  \</mso:ribbon\>" & vbNewLine

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "\</mso:customUI\>"

ribbonXML = Replace(ribbonXML, """", "")

Open path5 & fileName10 For Output Access Write As hFile

Print #hFile, ribbonXML

Close hFile

End Sub

I tried on new module with below code to get the value as "onChange" parameter but not working
Sub LoadCustomRibbon(control As IRibbonControl, editBox2 As String)

MsgBox editBox2

End Sub


Until using a control event, do you try suggesting that the above code really creates such a custom ribbon tab? Where from did you take the above code? Why building a path with double backslash separator ("\")? Which to be the meaning of the backlash starting any line? A tag is closed with /> not \>. Then, you should use a call to a function defined in XML. Your code has onLoad to firstly be called to define a ribbon variable. To be used when Invalidate controls/ribbon itself. Related to that control, only editBox1 call can be called (with  appropriate parameters)...

Sorry Duru, the tags in XML were automatically changed/ generated with wrong tag closure after it has been posted. I originally pasted like below.

ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "        <mso:group id='text' label='FILE LOCATION' autoScale='true'>" & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "          <mso:editBox id='editBox' getText='editBox1' " & vbNewLine
ribbonXML = ribbonXML + "     label='Location'  onChange='editBox2'/> " & vbNewLine
It creates me the ribbon successfully,  how to get values from edit box. Could you please share me in VBA code format , so i can copy paste.

If the new ribbon tab is created, you should declare a Public variable on top of a standard module: Public myRibbon As IRibbonUI. Then, some Subs. The first one should be Sub onLoad(ribbon As IRibbonUI) Set myRibbon = ribbon End Sub. Then Sub editBox1(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef returnedVal) returnedVal = "My text test" End Sub... To get the text you need to have OnChange edit box event (in XML) onChange="Edit_OnChange"... In VBA Sub Edit_OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, id As String) MsgBox id End Sub. The first Sub must exist when ribbon is loaded!

Hi FaneDuru thanksvery much for your time.
I'm getting an 'Argument not optional' error when call the sub Edit_OnChange

Not working bro, any other way/code or else is it possible to share my excel in this forum. Please let me know so i can share my excel to you

Please, try Sub Edit_OnChange(control As IRibbonControl, text As String). And MsgBox text instead of text . I took the event code from a combo box (in my testing environment, supposing that they should be similar)... I cannot test such a workbook. Doing that, I risk to ruin my "Excel.officeUI" file. I have more add-ins, each of them which its own tab(s)... You need to place back the initial such file when closing the workbook, anyhow. I never used this way, which is not safe from the above mentioned point of view. Another way would be to write the necessary XML inside the zipped wb...
